# Robocopy "modified"

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, backup, script, command-line-arguments

Using robocopy on Windows 8 to automate backing up several different groups of files.

It labels all of them as "MODIFIED" all the time though even if I just ran it and haven't touched the files.

How can I fix this?

This one is supposed to copy my PDF collection from "My Documents" onto a USB, and it is now marking everything as "modified." `robocopy /mir "C:\users\alex\documents\books and information" "Z:\Books and Information"`

I'd also like to add some additional info: It IS copying files like it should, but it is saying "modified" where I was expecting "skipped" and copying files that are unchanged which just wastes time.

Answer (score 3):

What format is your USB drive?  If it is FAT, then use the /fft parameter (try this parameter regardless).

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

Try either the `/XC` switch which will eXclude Changed Files or try `/fft` which will account for a 2 second delay in a previous copy.